# Create object with name and the typed value of a property of a type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following types:

```
export interface PatchOperation<T> {
  from?: keyof T;
  op: OperationType;
  path: keyof T;
  value?: T[keyof T];
}

interface Parent {
  creation: Date;
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

How can I enforce that `PatchOperation<Parent>.value` has the correct type for `PatchOperation<Parent>.path`.

So that the code below generates an error:

```
const update: PatchOperation<Parent> = {
  op: OperationType.Replace,
  path: 'creation',
  value: 'string', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be improved using [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), so you won't need to pass key type explicitly:

```
export type PatchOperation<T, K = keyof T> = K extends keyof T ? {
  op: OperationType;
  path: K;
  value?: T[K];
} : never;
```

Now we get the error as expected:

```
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date | undefined'
const update: PatchOperation<Parent> = {
  op: OperationType.Replace,
  path: 'creation',
  value: 'string',
};
```

---

> Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation

So in our example `PatchOperation<Parent>` will be equivavlent to:

```
{
    op: OperationType;
    path: "creation";
    value?: Date;
} | {
    op: OperationType;
    path: "id";
    value?: number;
} | {
    op: OperationType;
    path: "name";
    value?: string;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gDsATgQwC4EsD2IAqBPBKAbwFgAoKKAJWDgBtkBjYcgX3POAA85NFUoqAsCgAFNIwAW8JGiwgAPDgA0UANJQAvFADWwPJgBmUHAD4t6qN1SgAJgGdd+oyagB+YuUqY4ALlgIKBjY+AgA3F5QcGiS-moRFFAAbsh0YMBu-jgA2moAugmsUP4gwElICeToIDaIhkwi4oigAqSJjM1y2P4AImjACZTotiWQAEYVkSDIEMD+9qiI1QDmhRxkjNgLUGBwtv3+4qhSMkHyCk0t5tpt3n4BssG4wgB0NPQNypHRqLFQAOQdYBdED-L6JFJpOYAhZLEDLMFQAD0SJMwhhixW-yg6EcIEwAmQ9ns6GW0zGdBEqEwgnR-z6Nn+LzYlQ2W0wlJedEwywAFLt9jYAJSslFiCTSQIgi7IZo1cy4qwARzA6BSSUpNUEmHIYraYsod38pxBoQGutRhqiMX8ACIgSDbQkDYbIelMlAGeayGKigAfTw+y2GnzGqVPM3O4OUH5-W3DJ0Wq3JVLu0YQCaIKNQf2Bl1Gh5nELCbNW2N26azRNB5NujLzTHw7OsIA)

Answer (score 0):

Not as practical as I would like but it works by adding a second generic parameter corresponding to the name of the property.

```
export interface PatchOperation<T, P extends keyof T> {
  from?: keyof T;
  op: OperationType;
  path: keyof T;
  value?: T[P];
}

interface Parent {
  creation: Date;
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const update: PatchOperation<Parent, 'creation'> = {
  op: OperationType.Replace,
  path: 'creation',
  value: 'string', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.ts(2322)
};

const update: PatchOperation<Parent, 'creation'> = {
  op: OperationType.Replace,
  path: 'creation',
  value: new Date(), // ok
};
```

Pratical use:

```
type PatchDocument<T, P extends keyof T> = PatchOperation<T, P>[];

const update = createAction(
    '[Project] Update Project',
    props<{
      operation : PatchDocument<ProjectDTO, keyof ProjectDTO>
    }>()
  );
```